# When using the precise definition of a limit, why can't we just directly solve for x

Tags: limits, inequality

I recognize that often, it is not possible to algebraically solve an inequality directly for x, but in the case where it is possible, why is it that textbooks often use an alternative method. Please consider example 1 (attached below). Would this be a valid method of proving the limit? If yes, why is it that textbooks often choose seemingly more confusing methods (for limits which can be proved algebraically)?

EDIT: Thanks to a commenter, I realized that I made an algebraic mistake in example 2 (forgot to reverse inequalities when taking reciprocal. Other than this mistake, would taking  = 4ɛ/(1-2ɛ) be a valid way of proving the limit?
[image]

Comment: The logic does *not* break down, but you have a calculation mistake. When you took reciprocals (to convert inequalities about $\frac{1}{x}$ to inequalities around $x$), you forgot to flip the sign ($<$ to $>$).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Does that mean the logic for example 1 is valid? And for example 2, does that mean taking   = 4ɛ/(1-2ɛ) would be a valid way of proving the limit?

Comment: I don’t see a problem with either $1$ or (patched up) $2$, in principle. There may be a potential issue when $\epsilon$ is big, say $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ in the second case. This is of course a very small problem (if you find $\delta$ for a smaller $\epsilon$, you’ve found automatically for any bigger $\epsilon$) - however you are trying to solve for the *exact* bound for *any* $\epsilon$ and so may need to deal with different cases (big $\epsilon$ vs. small $\epsilon$) that you won’t need to care about otherwise.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. I haven't seen any other textbooks/sources use this method (and honestly, I can see why; I prefer the usual method), but I was just wondering if this was because the method was not valid or some other reason.

Comment: (What I want to say is - your method of course works, but may be more work to pull off than the less exact methods.)

Comment: There is an error in example $1.$ The quantity $\delta$ should be defined as $$\delta=\min \{2-\sqrt[3]{8-\varepsilon},\sqrt[3]{8+\varepsilon}-2\}$$ In example $2$ you have to assume that $\varepsilon <{1\over 2}.$

Comment: As to the motivation for textbooks showing other, more complicated methods it's done because they want to expose you to a variety of techniques. Some approaches generalize more readily than those when you can explicitly solve for $x$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ah yes because the first quantity would be negative so I would need to take the absolute value of that. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: In the second example $\delta={4\varepsilon\over 2\varepsilon +1}$ as it is smaller than ${4\varepsilon\over 1-2\varepsilon }$ for $\varepsilon <{1\over 2}$